# adjustI can't access a folder from my xammp server

Tags: php, installation, xampp

I downloaded a CRM application based on PHP. I want to try it on my XAMMP Server. I install it. But I can not login because of 404 error.

Then I rename index.php file, and 
Then I noticed that an entire folder never appeared on my webpage. Normally, There are a "application" folder. But it is missing.[That is appearence of my Chrome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcBU9.png)

just a note : I activate mod_rewrite

Please Help me

This problem is valid for me. And I cant take a good answer. But, you vote down, and I cant ask question. Bravo!

Comment: Revert back the file to index.php and check Apache error log. Identify and fix the error.

Comment: 'code'[Fri Jul 21 14:36:01.525124 2017] [authz_core:error] [pid 16892:tid 1912] [client ::1:11445] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/htdocs/CRM/Ultimate Project Manager CRM PRO/FRESH_FILES/system/, referer: http://localhost/CRM/Ultimate%20Project%20Manager%20CRM%20PRO/ 'code' that is error but I can nıt ıdentify :(

Comment: Seems like some other applications running on port 80 (I'm not 100% but there are chances for this). If you are using Skype, stop Skype and try again.

Comment: I checked port 80. But there are no other software. but thanks

Comment: If the port was in-use then Apache won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Apache-server (XAMP) user have permissions to access the directory. Also, make sure that your `redirect` mentioned points to a place that exist.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'll up-vote, but I have to make edits.

Comment: Yes I have permission. I am using a windows OS. I adjust permission.
Right click - Properties - Security - all permissions for all users